# Why aren't drawing exceptions caught when I explicitly ask a control to redraw?

Tags: .net, exception, c++-cli, charts, data-visualization

I have a GUI app which displays data using a `Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Chart` which works fine most of the time. Just occasionally we get some spurious data which the chart control doesn't like which throws an exception. To try and capture what it is that causes these problems I've wrapped the re-draw request in a try/catch:

```
try
{
    m_chart->Invalidate();
    m_chart->Update();
}
catch(System::Exception^ e)
{
    // If something goes wrong during the drawing, we probably want to try 
    // and record some more information then re-throw it so we can capture 
    // it properly.
    String^ detailString = String::Format("Exception caught while trying to draw raw data. {0}", "Add more debug info here");
    throw gcnew System::Exception(detailString, e);
}
```

...for some reason though, the exception isn't thrown there (I have a breakpoint and some logging which never get hit) - it happens at some other point:

```
Exception:
    Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal.
Exception type:
    System.OverflowException
Source:
    mscorlib
Stack trace:
   at System.Decimal..ctor(Double value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis.RoundedValues(Double inter, Boolean shouldStartFromZero, Boolean autoMax, Boolean autoMin, Double& min, Double& max)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis.EstimateNumberAxis(Double& minimumValue, Double& maximumValue, Boolean shouldStartFromZero, Int32 preferredNumberOfIntervals, Boolean autoMaximum, Boolean autoMinimum)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis.EstimateAxis(Double& minimumValue, Double& maximumValue, Boolean autoMaximum, Boolean autoMinimum)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis.EstimateAxis()
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.SetDefaultAxesValues()
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.SetData(Boolean initializeAxes, Boolean checkIndexedAligned)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.ReCalcInternal()
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPicture.Paint(Graphics graph, Boolean paintTopLevelElementOnly)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer, Boolean disposeEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
Installed .net Versions:
    v2.0.50727.5420
    v3.0.30729.5420
    v3.5.30729.5420
    v4.0.30319
```

Have I missed something here? Does invalidate / update not trigger the same re-draw that some other part of the windows message pump does?

Answer (score 0):

Most UI frameworks follow this kind of pattern. `Invalidate`, etc. just update flags in the window state so that it will be repainted later.

If you can't catch the error in the painting code, you'll have to handle [`ThreadException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx). Catching the error in the painting (or data binding) code is the preferred solution, but if you're just temporarly adding a handler to see what the data is, `ThreadException` should work fine.

Comment: That's why I call `Invalidate` and then `Update`; the docs say that should force the control to redraw: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx

Comment: You're correct; `Update` will repaint that control if necessary, but I believe you should pass `true` to `Invalidate` to ensure it is repainted immediately.

Comment: The doc's suggest passing a boolean tells a control to invalidate it's children: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz8ytzt0.aspx ?

Comment: For the record, I already handle `ThreadException` which is how I was capturing the bug reports I mentioned in my question. As I stated there though, it would be nice to be able to capture more information as to why the crash might be occurring.